# Ocaml Opam install camlbz2

Tags: ocaml, opam

Error while installing camlbz2

%opam install camlbz2

```
...
...
. checking bzlib.h usability... no
. checking bzlib.h presence... no
. checking for bzlib.h... no
```

awk: line 1: regular expression compile failed (syntax error ^* or ^+)
^+
configure: error: not found 'opam install camlbz2' failed.
I can not find anything for opam to install something like "libbz2" or whatever, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

OPAM only deals (currently) with OCaml source packages.

Here, your problem comes from the `./configure` script of the OCaml package detecting that a *system package* is missing, not an OCaml package (you can see that it has searched for files with a `.h` extension, i.e. a C include file).

To fix your problem, you need to install this system package. As Ontologiae said, the missing package is related to the `libbz2` library, and include files are usually provided in development packages, so you should probably try to install `libbz2-dev` using the system installer of your OS. This package is not in OCaml, so there is no risk of messing up with OPAM installation.

Note that, since you use `opam config -env` to set your OCaml environment, even if you install OCaml packages with your system installer, there should be no bad interaction with packages installed in your homedir by OPAM.

Answer (score 4):

You need to install the libbz2 C library. So, check your package system and install it.

In Debian, it's the package "libbz2-dev" (so sudo apt-get install libbz2-dev)

Comment: But I am using OPAM, Things will get messed up if I sudo apt-get.

Comment: I need OPAM to install this for me, anyidea?

Comment: OPAM only deals with ocaml stuff, just like rubygems takes care of ruby stuff, or cabal for haskell. libbz2 is a C library, and you should be able to install it by hand or with your system native package manager without interfering with OPAM.